# unable to sum the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am totally puzzled with output of sql query. Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
    PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY, 
    SUM(MySum) Orig_Qty
FROM
    Test 
GROUP BY
    PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY
```

This query doesn't sum and return a single row. I expect `Orig_Qty` to be 340.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d36f2/4)

I expect the following output:

[image]

Comment: @JohnCappelletti i tried but it still doesnt sum

Comment: *"I am totally puzzled with output of sql query"* You don't have to SQL Server makes the correct result that is the expected result from that query.. I think you want a "running" sum instead? see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d36f2/11 .. Otherwise see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for also providing the expected results.

Comment: the expected results does not match your query attempt because it is missing `ORIGINAL_QUANTITY` column??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORIGINAL_QUANTITY` differs between these two rows, that's why you didn't get `340`. Use this:

```
SELECT PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION, SUM(MySum) Orig_Qty
from Test r 
Group by PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION
```

Comment: @James if the expected result is really the results (see mine comment under the question) you expect then this query will give that result..

Comment: My query returns your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery

```
select sum(Orig_Qty) q from
    (SELECT PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY, SUM(MySum) Orig_Qty
    from Test r 
    Group by PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION, ORIGINAL_QUANTITY
    ) a
```

or simply use as you need only sum of qty

```
SELECT  SUM(MySum) Orig_Qty
from Test r
```

if you need all column wth sum then use window function

```
SELECT distinct PROJECT_ID, ACTIVITY_RUB4, CALCULATION_VERSION, 
SUM(MySum) over() Orig_Qty
from Test r 

PROJECT_ID  ACTIVITY_RUB4   CALCULATION_VERSION     Orig_Qty
36002       12.C01-01-RP       V001                  340
```

Comment: but i need all columns in select